# can't access Google Play Games API when released the app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I developed an app in which I used Google Play Games API.
When I was testing it all seemed fine, but since I released my app it stoped working.

I know that I should link my app to APIs. I followed many answers on StackExchange and it still does not work.

My situation is the following: I uploaded the release build to Google Play Developer Console, I added my app to Google Play Games section in my Google Play Developer Console. What it resulted in is that there were automatically created client IDs in the Google Play API Console. Also I made sure that the Games Library is enabled.

So in theory it has to work, but it does not :)

Help me please..

[image: SCREENSHOT Google Play Games Developer Console]

[image: SCREENSHOT Google Play Developer API Console]

Logs dont seem to show any relevant information.. But here they are:

```
02-18 13:15:31.562 1165-1437/? I/PlayCommon: [93] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(1049): Connecting to server: https:// play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
02-18 13:26:57.199 550-579/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/15/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
02-18 13:28:42.017 550-579/? E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-18 13:28:49.979 1165-1165/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
02-18 13:28:52.304 1165-1437/? I/PlayCommon: [93] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(1049): Connecting to server: https:// play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
02-18 13:28:52.777 1165-1165/? I/PlayCommon: [1] com.google.android.play.dfe.api.b.a(20553): Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https : //android.clients.google.com/fdfe/api/userProfile 0xe8d195d1 NORMAL 63]
02-18 13:28:52.809 1165-1165/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.api.a.i.a(50039): Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https:// android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=com.vladislavzhabinsky.fiveinarow 0xe8d195d1 NORMAL 65]
02-18 13:29:12.255 1165-1165/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
02-18 13:29:18.484 8986-8986/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/15/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
02-18 13:29:19.347 8986-9062/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/15/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
02-18 13:29:19.440 8986-9011/? W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
02-18 13:29:19.440 8986-9011/? W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
02-18 13:29:20.285 9093-9113/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/15/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation - [API_UNAVAILABLE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#API_UNAVAILABLE):

> One of the API components you attempted to connect to is not available. The API will not work on this device or for your app or for this particular account, and updating Google Play services will not likely solve the problem.

You might also want to check if your have set all settings correctly, check the [certificate and keystore](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) if they are for your release build also stated in this [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61692/google-play-services-authentication-in-xamarin) and if the API is enabled.

Hope this helps.